# How to connect to ProjectModels created by localDB using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am using Visual Studio 17 and in my project using Entity Framework databases are created under `(localdb)\ProjectModels`

[image: ProjectModels]

I am able to connect to `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` but not to `(localdb)\ProjectModels`. When i try

[image: Cannot connect to (localdb)\ProjectModels]

I receive error saying "cannot connect to (localdb)\ProjectModels"

What am I missing?

Turns out the SqlLocaldb instance was not running. So what did was to run the instance ProjectModels using command line sqlLocaldb

```
sqllocldb i
sqllocaldb start ProjectModels
```

[image: sqllocaldb start ProjectModels]

then using SQL Server Management Studio i connected using

[image: (localdb\ProjectModels)]

it was then visible in the Object explorer

[image: SSMS Object explorer]

Comment: What error did the system report when you could not connect to (localdb)\ProjectModels?

Comment: cannot connect to (localdb)\ProjectModels

Comment: Open the SqlServer configuration manager => SqlServer service, and then check the instance status corresponding to your (localdb)\ProjectModels. If it is stopped, you can right-click to start it. If its startup mode is manual, you can right-click properties => service => start mode to automatic